Embedded iframe not showing up
I am new to HTML and working on website designing, so please take this into account when replying. As the title says I have a problem with a iframe that does not embed correctly into a website design on wordpress.com. Thanks for your help in advance!
The iframe looks the following and contains a 3D tour from CloudPano. The argument behind the "scr" key is directly taken from the CloudPano embedment link and correctly directs to the GSV tour.
<iframe src="https://app.cloudpano.com/tours/sometour" data-path="tours" data-is-self-hosted="false" width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>

The iframe is just not showing up in on the website. Is there something wrong with the html tag or rather with the policies of the website server on remote content etc.?

When I put this into a jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/2d1uykpj/ - the iframe itself appears to load the specified URL to begin with - but then there's internal server errors in the console, for other resources it tries to load. Is that about the same result you are getting on your site?
